# Teradata SQL - If condition A1 then evaluate condition b1...for A1,A2,A3

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, where-clause, teradata

[image]

This should produce -

```
au  123  john
ph  456  pipin
nz  765  myers
nz  876  philip
```

Comment: what have you tried so far and if there is what's the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to slightly change the syntax in your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT
    country,
    account_num,
    name
FROM table
WHERE
    country = 'au' AND account_num <> '999' OR
    country = 'ph' AND account_num <> '888' OR
    country = 'br' AND account_num <> '555';
```

Answer (score 1):

Added another condition to catch the countries other than 'au','ph' or 'br':

```
SELECT
    country,
    account_num,
    name
FROM table
WHERE
   (country = 'au' AND account_num <> '999') OR
   (country = 'ph' AND account_num <> '888') OR
   (country = 'br' AND account_num <> '555') OR
   country not in ('au', 'ph', 'br');
```

Comment: You don't need the parentheses around the ANDed terms, because and has higher precedence than OR.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Of course, but whenever you mix AND and or you should write them anyway, it's much easier to understand (and not everyone knows the NOT/AND/OR precedence rule by heart) and to extend with other additional conditions

Comment: @dnoeth I completely agree with you that it is generally much cleaner code and easier to read.